# Refresh listView from PopUntil

Tags: flutter

Just wonder if I use this code to return PageA from PageD, which function will it get called in PageA?

**PageD**

`Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(PageA.ROUTE));`

I would like to make the listView on `PageA` refreshed once it is back from PageD, but I don't know how to achieve it.

I added a `then` in `PageA`, but it is not printing anything.

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, PageB.ROUTE).then((onValue) {
       print("call from Page4");
       _refreshListView();
});
```

**Edit**

My project flow is Page A > Page B > Page C > Page D > page A.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All you need to do is return data when you pop `PageD` and await the data when you push.

This code should help:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/' : (context) => PageA(),
        '/go': (context) => PageD()
      },
    );
  }
}

class PageA extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page A"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[

          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _navigateAndDisplaySelection(context);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.forward),
      ),
    );
  }

  _navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
    final result = await Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        '/go'
    );

    if(result){
      print(result);
      //call the refresh ListView here
      _refreshListView();
    }
  }
}

class PageD extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page D"),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white,),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context, true);
          },
        )
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Press back!!"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As to what you explained in the comments... you have to pass arguments from Page D to A when navigating.
Hope this helps.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => PageA(),
        '/b': (context) => PageB(),
        '/c': (context) => PageC(),
        '/d': (context) => PageD()
      },
    );
  }
}

class PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool shouldRefresh = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    if (shouldRefresh != null) {
      print(shouldRefresh);

      //call the refresh ListView here
      _refreshListView();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page A"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/b');
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.forward),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page B"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.forward),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/c');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageC extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page C"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.forward),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/d');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageD extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Page D"),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/', arguments: true);
            },
          )),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Press back!!"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to go to Page D when you press back in Page A then use this

```
class PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool shouldRefresh = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    print(shouldRefresh);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page A"),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(
                context,
                '/d',
                arguments: true
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[

          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/b');
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.forward),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need go from PageA to B , C then D. Then only D to A.

Comment: How are you moving from one page to another, pushReplacement? or just push? if you just push from A to B, C then D and you want to push from D to A then you have to pass arguments from D to A...I'll edit my answer to show an example

Comment: If I press back in PageA, will it open pageD?

Comment: No, but you can make that possible..I'll add it to the update

Comment: Updated...check it out

Comment: Sorry give you unclear info. When I press back button in PageA, I don't want open page D . That's why I use popUtil.

Comment: Oh I get you now